# Update placeholder by id using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input field in html which is created 'dynamically' in a function say :

```
'<input id="id1'+var1+'" name="id1" type="text" placeholder="Provide IP"/>'
```

In the same function in javascript, I'm trying to change the placeholder text by :

```
$("#id1"+var1).attr("placeholder",arr[i]);
```

It doesn't work!!The array arr also gets updated in the function
Also further options like :

```
$("#id1"+var1).attr("placeholder",arr[i]).blur();
$("#id1"+var1).attr("placeholder",arr[i]).placeholder();
$("#id1"+var1).attr("placeholder",arr[i]).val("").focus().blur();
```

doesn't work. It is retaining previous placeholder text only!! How to resolve this? I'm using Google Chrome

Comment: All are working fine for me

Comment: Its working fine check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: your first example works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/Lgaboj5y/

Comment: I suspect you have another element with the _same_ ID before the element you are trying to change.

Comment: you have it in document ready?

Comment: what does this `id="id1"+var1 ` suppose to mean?

Comment: var1 is a variable say, which is assigned a value based on some event. so the id is : id1+(the value of var1)

Comment: any chance that you are trying to set placeholder before inserting the field?Try using `.prop()` also.

Comment: No. Input field has been added. Only after that I'm trying to modify placeholder

Comment: try using `.prop()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are missing to do the change after the dom is loaded. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#id1").attr("placeholder","IP changed"); 
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0;
  var j = i - 1
  var myArray = ["firts text", "second text", "and so on"]
  $("#button").click(function() {
    if (i > 2) {
      i = 0;
    }
    $('input').each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('placeholder') == "Provide IP" || $(this).attr('placeholder') == myArray[j]) {
        $(this).attr("placeholder", myArray[i]);
        return false;
      }
    })
    i++;
    j++;
    if (j > 2) {
      j = i - 1;
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id1" name="id1" type="text" placeholder="Provide IP" />
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click me" />
```

Comment: What if I want to use an array value. Say arr[i]. Here I have provided a string. But later on I'm planning to provide a CIDR which is in the array. Will that be resolved?

Comment: Then you just put the array in the position of the string, like this: $("#id1").attr("placeholder",myArray[i]);

Comment: the input has been created dynamically. I have modified the question. Please check

Comment: Is there only one input? Check my updated code snipped above.

Comment: have a look at the id: It is "id1"+var1 , var1 is also a dynamically created variable which is appended to the id in the function

Comment: then you use $("input[type='text']").attr() to select a input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126795/discussion-between-zorken17-and-prasita-mukherjee).